# Using Android Hidden API to access Fingerprint information

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I'm working with Android Hidden API for an educational purposes project at the university. In particular, I'm playing with fingerprint authentication. My goal is to take the `Fingerprint` object from the `AuthenticationResult`. AuthenticationResult has two getter: `getCryptoObject()` and `getFingerprint()`. The last one is hidden (and also `Fingerprint` class has `@hide` annotation), so I can't call it. Then I found this repository (see https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api), so I replaced the `android.jar` into my sdk location. Doing so, I'm able to access to the `Fingerprint` class and also call `getFingerprint()`, but it returns null. I wonder if my device should have a `framework.jar` version with hidden api enabled (the same that I actually use to build the app in Android Studio) or if, simply, we can't access these information (so the Fingerprints).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For a GMS certified device, you won't be able to access the fingerprints on Android 6.0+.

See:
https://source.android.com/compatibility/7.1/android-7.1-cdd.pdf

Section: 7.3.10

Highlights:

- MUST have a hardware-backed keystore implementation, and perform the fingerprint matching in a Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) or on a chip with a secure channel to the TEE.
- MUST have all identifiable fingerprint data encrypted and cryptographically authenticated such that they cannot be acquired, read or altered outside of the Trusted Execution Environment (TEE) as documented in the implementation guidelines on the Android Open Source Project site.
- MUST NOT enable 3rd-party applications to distinguish between individual fingerprints.