# Generate my own key to authenticate fingerprint android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, fingerprinting

I am creating my first android app (for beginners) and I want users to login using fingerprint

Apparently android stores the fingerprint secretly and I cant access the hashed version.

Is there anyway to create a fingerprint algorithm to be able to get a hashed key from each fingerprint in my app ?
I want to see the fingerprint and hash it myself

I hope i was clear in my question :(

Comment: Nope, not possible: [Using Android Hidden API to access Fingerprint information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45579093/295004)